# CloudFormation Template - Setting Container Image by Parameter Selection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Looking to set a specified container image based on the selection of a parameter; say if the selection is "aceptance" the container image would point to the acceptance branch image, or "deploy" would point to deploy, etc..

Here is one attempt I have tried, but not sure if this is the best or allowed path. Upon Creating the Stack I receive an error:

```
ECSTaskDefinition CREATE_FAILED Invalid request provided: Create TaskDefinition: Container.name should not be null or empty. (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException; Request ID: b679c7be-ad3e-4791-b388-d2cb87332b94; Proxy: null)
```

```
Parameters:
    Branch:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
        - acceptance
        - canary
        - deploy
Mappings:
BranchSelection:
    acceptance:
        BranchType: "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/acceptance"
    canary:
        BranchType: "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/canary"
    deploy:
        BranchType: "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/deploy"

ECSTaskDefinition:
        Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
        Properties:
            ContainerDefinitions: 
              - 
                Environment: 
                  - 
                    Name: "ACCESS_KEY_ID"
                    Value:
                        !Sub
                            - "{{resolve:ssm:/doorways/${STAGE}/ACCESS_KEY_ID:1}}"
                            - { STAGE: !Ref STAGE }
                  - 
                    Name: "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
                    Value:
                        !Sub
                            - "{{resolve:ssm:/doorways/${STAGE}/AWS_SECRET_KEY:1}}"
                            - { STAGE: !Ref STAGE }                  
                  - 
                    Name: "SENDGRID_USERNAME"
                    Value:
                        !Sub
                            - "{{resolve:ssm:/doorways/${STAGE}/SENDGRID_USERNAME:1}}"
                            - { STAGE: !Ref STAGE }
                  - 
                    Name: "SENDGRID_PASSWORD"
                    Value:
                        !Sub
                            - "{{resolve:ssm:/doorways/${STAGE}/SENDGRID_PASSWORD:1}}"
                            - { STAGE: !Ref STAGE }
                  - 
                    Name: "REGION"
                    Value: !Ref AWS::Region                  
              -
                Essential: true                 
                Image: !FindInMap
                  - BranchSelection
                  - !Ref Branch
                  - BranchType
                LogConfiguration: 
                    LogDriver: "awslogs"
                    Options: 
                        awslogs-group: "/ecs/doorways-task-definition"
                        awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
                        awslogs-stream-prefix: "ecs"
                Name:
                    !Sub
                        - 'dw-${FriendlyName}-${SiteId}-${STAGE}'
                        - { FriendlyName: !Ref FriendlyName, SiteId: !Ref SiteId, STAGE: !Ref STAGE }
                PortMappings: 
                  - 
                    ContainerPort: 3000
                    HostPort: 3000
                    Protocol: "tcp"
              -
```

Has anyone had a similar use case, and could possibly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

[Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-environment.html) must have at least one:

```
  Name: String
  Value: String
```

You don't have any. Also your `FindInMap` will not work they way you think it will. The values `${AWS::AccountId}` and `${AWS::Region}` will not be substituted and you will end up with literal strings.

Comment: @JeffreyMastera If your question is not representative of your actual template and issue, then its rather difficult to speculate on the cause of your difficulties.

Comment: updated original question with the section of the ECSTaskDefinition relevant to my question.  Editing the Mappings to be the full path to the container results in the same error.

Comment: I've also taken out the Mappings, and replace the Image path with a !Join to no avail
```
    Image: !Join ['.', [!Ref AWS::AccountId, 'dkr.ecr', !Ref AWS::Region, 'amazonaws.com/!Ref Branch']]
```
Reverting back to a single static Image path such as below works just fine
```
    Image: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/branchabc"
```

Comment: @JeffreyMastera Are you sure that this is your correct template? Because your first container in `ContainerDefinitions` has only `Environment` and nothing else. No Image or any other parameters.

Comment: I can share my template in its entirety, just wasn't sure if that was acceptable. it is 446 lines

Comment: @JeffreyMastera There is no need for full template. Just double check formatting on SO. Your fist container definition has only `Environment`. Is this actual the case, or when you copped and pasted did the template tabulation got modified?

Comment: reverted back to a previous version of my template (where in essence I am statically pointing all new "sites" to a single branch\container) and re entered the Mappings, and the FindInMap variable for the Image. Instead of the error in regards to container.name cannot be Null (obviously I had a errant space, comma, or something else off) I now get container.image contains invalid characters. From that I would infer that the Image variable does not like FindInMap

Comment: to answer the prior question, the Container Def has more than just Environment. My original post was modified, the new text includes a more detailed snippet from my template. Might just be the formatting that is slightly off with the copy paste